# What would be reasons for warfare to be fought primarily with vehicles?

Tags: warfare

World is just like ours.  Guns exist.

What would cause combat to be mainly vehicle centered.  For example why would the average infantrymen fight with a vehicle. Like a tank.

Comment: Welcome to WB:SE!  We appreciate your participation.  Please be aware that this question is off-topic as it is not about worldbuilding (creating the rules of your world) and unclear what you're asking because you haven't explained why things like "vehicles are too expensive for everyone to have one" wouldn't apply.  For more information you can see our [question FAQs](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  We invite you to edit your question and add the information that makes your world different from Earth.

Comment: @WorldCraftTrainee already mentions it in their answer but yes simply *Mad Max* can give you all the answers

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer I can think of is chemically contaminated 'badlands' style combat zones. Tanks and sealed light vehicles would give drivers freedom of movement to react in real time to combat situations, without having to wear bulky protection suits of some kind, that would risk rupture in conventional combat situations anyway.

Come to think of it, Quarian ground troops would have been better off fighting this way as well in the *Mass Effect* series.

Answer (score 1):

1. Mobility.  Troops need to move around quickly, so they use vehicles.
2. Bad terrain without roads (or insufficient roads).  So the troops need to use tracked vehicles rather than wheeled vehicles.
3. Common ambush weapons that would compromise less armored vehicles.  These could be Improvised Explosive Devices (IEDs) or just guns.

The first reason is necessary.  If there is little reason for mobility, then they would just build fortifications.  You could probably get away with just one of the last two reasons.  But both together are stronger.

Answer (score 1):

Bad terrain and hazardous conditions are some of the things i think would warrant the use of vehicles, but these are all around conditions and can be applied to various situations. So here are some of my suggestions for oddly specific reasons:

- Its their religion/belief to fight in war chariot like vehicles (think Mad Max)
- the scale of war has escalated exponentially, meaning that small troops and infantry can't fight against vehicular troops (think planetary conflicts and wars)
- mobility of vehicles have been accelerated faster than infantry can act, meaning that sabotage via speed is now more difficult not in a vehicle.
- more variant vehicles require less soldiers, thus reducing human causalities (needs a very good economy tho)
- vehicles don't need training, and can be diversified in their abilities: for example, a single mech could be outfitted to create paths, Anti Air defense, artillery support, and urban combat. A tank can easily equip a secondary other than its main cannon, like missiles, anti-missile defense, and troop transport.
- military vehicles are cool

Don't know if this is helpful, but it was fun for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Capturing territory in our world is done by vehicles. Holding territory or guerilla warfare is done by infantry.

Vehicles can carry heavy armor. They can carry weapons both devestating to massed infantry (fuel-air bombs, high caliber machine guns, tank shotguns) and devastating to their own kind. They can carry sophisticated electronics that allow them to engage from miles away, impossibly far for infantry to meaningfully reply (like ship mounted artillery, aircraft, or tanks). They can travel faster than a soldier can walk, and can often compensate for their own motion - meaning they can engage accurately at top speed. There's a very impressive video somewhere of an M1A1 jumping over an embankment at top speed and firing off a shot accurately.

Infantry, and only infantry really, can hold territory. They are the thousands of eyes, ears and minds performing routine patrols, investigating suspicious activity, taking action, doing the follow up, and living in the captured territory day and night.

Also only infantry are light and multi capable enough to perform guerilla warfare - hiding among buildings or brush, approaching a target for a specific purpose, doing the job, and disappearing before any response.

Comment: In a way, infantry are like an imported police force (sometimes including public services like public engineering, public medicine, legal services, housing, financing, food assistance, and so on).